# SQL Server: How to use Cursor to delete records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

We want to remove tons of obsolete data in a table, but this will lock table for a long while. Is is possible to use Cursor to delete, says, one hundred records per transaction in a while-loop ?

And where can I refer to the example?

Comment: If the amount of data you want to keep is small and you don't need the deletes in the transaction log, you might be better off copying the data you want to keep to a temp table, truncate your original table, then copying the data back.

Comment: Thx the nice suggestion, but it's dangerous since it's online and cannot predict when users will query that table. BTW: the table has grown to 4GB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
DECLARE @stillgoing bit;
SET @stillgoing = 1;

WHILE @stillgoing = 1
BEGIN
  DELETE TOP (100) YourTableName
  WHERE IsObsolete = 1;

  IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
      SET @stillgoing = 0;

  CHECKPOINT /* Will encourage the log to clear if it's in Simple recovery model */
END
```

Edit: This will only work in SQL 2005 and on. As we've just learned it's SQL 2000, this code instead:

```
DECLARE @stillgoing bit
SET @stillgoing = 1

SET ROWCOUNT 100

WHILE @stillgoing = 1
BEGIN
  DELETE YourTableName
  WHERE IsObsolete = 1

  IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
      SET @stillgoing = 0

  CHECKPOINT /* Will encourage the log to clear if it's in Simple recovery model */
END
```

And... Simple Recovery Model means that the log will truncate on checkpoints, rather than only when the log is backed up.

Comment: hi, what do u mean by Simple Recovery Model.

Comment: Hi, still not work; here is my query: DELETE TOP 100 XYZ WHERE DateCreated <= '2001/2/31'

Comment: Sorry - my comment about SQL 2000 was wrong. TOP wasn't supported then. Try putting this at the start, and removing the "TOP 100". `SET ROWCOUNT 100`

Comment: It means that the query will affect only 100 rows at a time.

Answer (score 1):

You can commit every 100 (or 1000, or whatever) records in the loop, releasing the lock and letting any pending operations get their work in.  Otherwise you're generating a huge transaction log which eats greater than O(n^2) time when it gets large.  This thing will be a large portion of the actual time spent, instead of getting the actual deleting done.  If you batch and commit, you're safer, rollback/log files won't grow like crazy, and locks are manageable.

If however you need that huge rollback as an option, there's 2 choices:

- Wait a long while
- Backup the table first and then do the batch deletes

Answer (score 1):

```
Declare MyPrimaryKey [SomeType]

Declare @MyCursor Cursor For 

Select MyPrimayKey from MyTable

Open @MyCursor

Fetch Next From @MyCursor

Into
  @MyPrimaryKey

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

BEGIN
   WaitFor Delay '00:00:05'

   Begin Transaction

   DELETE From MyTable where MyPrimaryKey = @MyPrimaryKey

   Commit Transaction

   Fetch Next From @MyCursor

   Into
     @MyPrimaryKey
END
```

Comment: If you post code like this T-SQL snippet, please highlight those lines and use the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar, or press Ctrl-K on your keyboard, to properly format that section as code so it can be display and syntax-highlighted nicely

Comment: What's the intent for WaitFor Delay?

Comment: the wait for delay is to pause and allow other transactions for the table to begin.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer broden my eyes.